# Is it bad security practice to use the same passphrase for your ssh keys and your password manager master password?

Tags: password-management, ssh-keys

Is it a bad security practice to use the same passphrase (assume strong, diceware-esque) for your ssh keys and your password manager master password?

Comment: It really depends on how secure you want to be. Personally I'd use and suggest a unique master password.

Comment: From a security perspective, its never a good idea to re-use anything.

Comment: @vishnunarayanan I'm aware of that but I've seen many people that are storing their password managers to keep their ssh passphrases. Is that scenario any more secure than just using the same passphrase on both the passwd manager and your ssh keys?

Answer (score 1):

As is so often the case, XKCD has already covered this topic:

([Source](https://www.xkcd.com/792/))

[image]

Comment: That may be a funny comic, but please can you extract the relevant information and provide a proper answer?

Comment: Outdated (Google is already evil ;) and it doesn't really apply here. I specifically describe the limited reuse scenario and it doesn't involve the use of the passphrase on any kind of webservice.